# WSO2 ESB Custom POJOCommand

Tags: java, wso2, esb

I need to write custom `POJOCommandMediator`. According to wso2doc I have to implement `org.apache.synapse.Command`. I create simple jar with one class:
...

```
public class PojoCommandMediator implements Command {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
}
```

But every time I deploy my jar i see

> Class not found in the path' error in Design Sequence editor.

I successfully wrote a custom class mediator before, but here I faces with some difficulties.

So, I have a few questions:

Is it right i have to create by hand mediators directory (by default it absent) and put my command mediator jar in: `ESB_HOME\repository\components\mediators` folder?

Is where any additional requirements for Custom POJO Command what I need to know except implement execute method and build jar for successful command class loading in wso2?

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the jar file with the custom POJOCommandMediator in the **ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib** folder. That way upon restart, the ESB will pick up your class.

---Edit---

Actual issue seems to be with the UI componenet which gives an Authorization error.
Instead of adding it through the design view, you can go to the source view of the proxy configuration and add the following.

```
<inSequence>
     <pojoCommand name="class-name"/>
</inSequence>
```

This way the POJOCommand will be deployed properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It will not take any effect and will not solve the problem, because to my mind PojoCommandMediator class doesn't extend some abstract mediator or implement any interface except Command. Yes ESB will pick up and put it in dropins directory as well. I tried this but 'Class not found' again. Accoriding to wso2 esb doc ESB_HOME/repository/components/lib directory is only for class mediators.

Comment: Thanks a lot! <pojoCommand name="class-name"/> works fine. It looks like a bug in UI.